# How do to do online and offline in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

How to do online and offline in socket io? Do i need redis to store the session or mongodb?

My attempt
Serverside

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('connected', 'Online');

  socket.disconnect('disconnect', function() {
     socket.emit('connected', 'offline');
  });

})
```

ClientSide

```
 socket.on('connected', function(data) {
    $('#userOnline').html(data);
  });
```

With the code above it is not consistent, sometimes it shows offline, sometimes it is not

Answer (score 0):

The corrrect way to listen when a socket disconnect is:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
......
});
```

And you could not emit to this socket inside the callback.

For an exact answer i would need know how you make the disconnection (server or client side) and who should receive the information, himself or others clients?